# Ci not outputting every mysql row into a selectbox

Tags: codeigniter

In Codeigniter how would I output all my database values into a selectbox? When I do the following I only get the first row outputted. It seems to cut off after the first. Any help?

```
<body> 
<form method="post" action="<?=base_url()?>index.php/admin/addImg">
img url <input name="imgURL" type="text" /><br />
<br />  select project <select name="selectedProject">
<?php $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM projects");
foreach ($query->result() as $row) { ?>
<option><?php echo $row->projectName.$row->projectId ?></option>
</select></form>
<?php } ?>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're closing your `select` within the first loop. Try something like this:

```
<select name="selectedProject">
    <?php foreach($query->result() as $row) {
        <option><?php echo $row->projectName.$row->projectId ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Also, CodeIgniter [provides a handy Form Helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html) for this type of thing.